# "Start each item on a new page" missing from Outlook 2007 Print

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, printing

The help guide says that to print a selected group of emails on separate pages, the "Start each item on a new page" option needs to be checked in the print dialogue box, with Memo format checked also, instead of Table.

Our user's "Start each item on a new page" is missing from this dialogue box.

Any reason why this should be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like is an officially acknowledged problem.  See [support.microsoft.com/kb/222320](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222320). The cause is that the format of the emails is HTML.  The problem does not exist when emails are of format RTF.

HTML emails go through a different print processor (related to the IE browser) which has less customisation available.